# How to use sendRedirect or session or forward to refresh my web page only one time?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Now in my page I have a parameter call personid,if visitor input the url like 
:`http://helloworld.com?personid=123`,and I will return the person information whitch personid is 123.I can not known whether this person is real.So I decide  when the person visit the page  first time,I will use sendRedirect and then attatch the other parameter.But now this way is wrong.Can I use session or other way to only refresh the page one time?

```
    <%
 String personid = request.getParameter("personid ");
String vpersonid= request.getParameter("vpersonid");
 if (vpersonid== null) {
  String url="http://myserver/distinguishusrtoken.do?redirect_uri=http://helloworld.com/index.jsp?personid=123&personid ="+personid ;   
  response.sendRedirect(url);
} 
%>
```

When people visit the web `http://helloworld.com?personid=123`,the final url is `http://helloworld.com?personid=123&ppersonid=123`;but if people see the keyword and input the url `http://helloworld.com?personid=123&ppersonid=123`  directly,althought it is a fake url,but I can not do anything.How to redirect  to the self page only one time?I try to use session,but it is a endless loop?

```
    <%
  String personid = request.getParameter("personid ");
 String vpersonid = request.getParameter("vpersonid "); 
 if(response.getHeader("personid")==null||!personid.equals(response.getHeader("personid"))){
String url="http://myserver/distinguishusrtoken.do?redirect_uri=http://helloworld.com/index.jsp?personid=123&personid ="+personid ; 
 vpersonid =personid ;
 response.setHeader("personid ", personid );
response.sendRedirect(url);  
} 
%>
```

Comment: Please, format your code properly and don't hesitate to use whitespaces. The code snippet above is unreadable

Comment: I think you need Authentication / AUthorization mechanisme and not somethinkg like above

Answer (score 1):

Every time you come up with such situation, I would recommend you to rethink you architecture and/or approach. For instance, for your current problem, I'd suggest you look toward to filters. It will allow you to keep your servlets and JPSs free from not specific tasks for them. I'm not going to post any code here, 'cause the question is a bit general, and would rather recommend to take a look at some examples of Filters in Internet. For example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-writing-filters.htm).

BTW, you added the tag `spring` to your question, so I can suppose you use Spring Framework in application. If it is true, framework can take on a lot of things, so you don't need to extract request parameters manually.